# How to extract the mimimum values from the list of list and give them a name in r

Tags: r

I have a list of a list with high complicated data. I would like to compare the values of each list and extract the smallest values. For simplicity, I provide a similar example.

```
s <- c(1,2,3)
ss <- c(4,5,6)
S <- list(s,ss)
h <- c(4,8,7)
hh <- c(0,3,4)
H <- list(h,hh)
HH <- list(S,H)
```

I would like to compare the element of each list with the element of the corresponding list and extract the smallest values. For example, the following are the values of `HH` list.

```
   > HH
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4 5 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 4 8 7

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0 3 4
```

Now, I would like to compare

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

with

```
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 4 8 7
```

For example, `1 < 4`, so I will select `1`. For the second element, `2 < 8`, so I will select `2`. So, I would like to compare the elements of `[[1]][[1]]` with the elements of `[[2]][[1]]`, and `[[1]][[2]]` with `[[2]][[2]]`.

Then, I would like to print the name of the list. For example,

I expected to have similar to the following:

`1 < 4, the first element of the first model is selected`.

Comment: @RonakShah I apologize for that.  Your help is really appreciated. It gave me an error, but then I notice the error is my mistake, not your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this -

```
Map(function(x, y) as.integer(x > y) + 1, HH[[1]], HH[[2]])

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 2 2
```

This gives the position of the element selected.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a general solution (i.e. if there are many list elements) `transpose` from `purrr` to rearrange the `list` elements, and then use `max.col` to get the index

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
HH %>%
  transpose %>%
  map(~ .x %>%
        invoke(cbind, .) %>% 
        multiply_by(-1) %>%
        max.col )
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 2 2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = function(...) max.col(-1 * cbind(...)), HH))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 2 2
```